# Different between anonymous function and directly calling the function in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry this is more about lack of enough JS knowledge I think but my question is in my component if I have
`<td>{() => this.renderCell(item, col)}</td>` method being used like that it won't work but being called normally like I have in the component below then it works: What's the difference?

```
class TableBody extends Component {
  renderCell = (item, column) => {
    if (column.content) return column.content(item);

    return _.get(item, column.path);
  };

  render() {
    const { data, columns } = this.props;
    return (
      <tbody>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <tr>
            {columns.map((col) => (
              <td>{this.renderCell(item, col)}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `() => this.renderCell(item, col)` this is not calling the function, it's just returning a new function which happens to call the function, but that new function never gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry that I can't just comment on this. But what happens is that when you call a function from inside an arrow function in React, like this:

```js
<td>{() => myFunction()}</td>
```

It runs when you perform a specific action on that element, for example, when you click on a button:

```js
<button onClick={() => myFunction} />
```

When you don't call it from inside an arrow function, like you are doing in your code snippet, that function gets called automatically, so, it renders your code:

```js
// Runs automatically
<td>{myFunction()}</td>

// Only on specific trigger:
<td>{() => myFunction()}</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your anonymous function was defined but not called, which means it never runs this.renderCell(). To call it, you need to write it as
`( () => /* function code */ )()`

In your case:
`<td>{(() => this.renderCell(item, col))()}</td>`

This is pretty unnecessary though, you should just do this: `<td>{this.renderCell(item, col)}</td>` (as you did in your second snippet)

Answer (score -1):

This is because what is expected inside the `<td></td>` is a function, not a function call. So, you could either say `handleSubmit` or `() => handleSubmit()`, because they are both referring to a function, not a function call. `handleSubmit()` however, is a function call.